# Automatically select the value stored in the database and rest shows as dropdown

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
<label for="inputday">Day of week:</label>
<select id="inputday" name="dow" class="form-control">

<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM day_of_week";
$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query); //$dbcon as php include which establishes db connection
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo '<option value="' . $row['DOW_ID'] . '" selected>' . $row['DOW_NAME'] . '</option>';
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($dbcon);
?>

</select>
</div>
```

The above code displays all the values from the table `day_of_week` as a dropdown list. But I am unable to figure out how to automatically show one of the value as `selected` which matches a value already stored in a variable.

Example: If `$x = 3`, and `$x == $row['DOW_ID']`, how do I automatically show the value as selected?

Comment: What have you tried to make that work?

Comment: You are setting the HTML option to `selected` for each and every option, where you should set it only when the option matches the database record.

Comment: @Code4R7 yeah, just noticed, my bad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an `if` statement inside of your loop.

```
<select id="inputday" name="dow" class="form-control">
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM day_of_week";
$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query);
foreach($result as $row) {
    if($x == $row['DOW_ID']) {
        echo '<option value="' . htmlspecialchars($row['DOW_ID']) . '" selected>' . htmlspecialchars($row['DOW_NAME']) . '</option>';
    } else {
        echo '<option value="' . htmlspecialchars($row['DOW_ID']) . '" >' . htmlspecialchars($row['DOW_NAME']) . '</option>';
    }
}
?>
</select>
```